# Formatting Dates into Words

Tags: sql, oracle, date-formatting

I want to display the dates when the employees in the departments reach their twenty year working anniversary. This is what I have:

```
    select e.last_name, e.department_id, add_months(min(h.start_date), 240) as "20 Year Anniversary"
    from employees e
    inner join job_history h
    on h.employee_id = e.employee_id
    group by e.department_id, e.last_name;
```

This displays:

```
    Last_Name   Department_ID    20 Year Anniversary
  1 Hartstein              20    17-FEB-16
  2 Bob                    90    21-SEP-09
```

And so on. But I want to display the dates in this format: January twenty-one, Nineteen Eighty-Two. How would I format the dates?

Comment: What's that `GROUP BY` for? So that all Smith in the buying department have their aniversary on the same date? That doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - it's getting the earlest start date for each employee from their job history? But yes, the employee ID needs to be included in the group-by, doesn't it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is you are looking for. `TO_CHAR` date formatting.Check out official doc page of oracle

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm

```
select e.last_name, e.department_id,to_char(add_months(min(h.start_date), 240),'Month fmDdsp, Year') as "20 Year Anniversary"
    from employees e
    inner join job_history h
    on h.employee_id = e.employee_id
    group by e.department_id, e.last_name;
```

Comment: I'd put the FM modifier before the month so that isn't padded with spaces?

Comment: Thanks Faz, at first I thought I needed to concatenate, but that didn't work. And thank you Alex, for the space suggestions.

Comment: If i write Month it gets spelled easily but if i write Day or day it will give the name of the day in a week . So if want it spelled I'll put fm before Dd (coz i am targeting day to be transformed nothing else)  and later specify how do i want it to be spelled (sp/spth) @AlexPoole

Comment: Not sure what you mean; `fmddsp` gets the same answer as just `ddsp`, it isn't padded the way month and day are by default. But `month` is padded, while `fmmonth` is not.

Comment: Fm will just fill the blank spaces. Thats all. @AlexPoole is absolutely right